# Duplicate div tags created when importing data from a jquery ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm using a script that imports data from another page's  into the current pages  of the same ID using the .load() ajax function.  Here is the line of importance:
$('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())

Where toLoad is a variable containing say "about.html #content".  That works fine.  However I end up with an extra set of div tags around my original div.  It is importing the text along with the  tags from the other page and putting them inside my original div tags.  This causes my page not to look right with the nesting duplicate divs because of margins, etc. As far as I know this .load() is supposed to be used for this purpose so I must be doing something wrong.  Before I ask "how do you strip html tags from an ajax load?" I'm just wondering if this is normal behavior.  If so then yes, how do you strip html tags from an ajax load before importing the content?  Also, it seems to add a style='display:block' inline to the parent div.  That doesn't seem to be a problem but I don't need it to do that either.  Thanks~

Here is the whole script if you're interested:

```
$('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

});
```

Comment: Yes, this is normal behavior. `.load()` doesn't replace the element you apply it to, it sets that element's inner HTML to the HTML that the AJAX call returns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble loading table after ajax POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328867/having-trouble-loading-table-after-ajax-post)

Comment: Ok thanks for the confirmation.  I fixed it by creating a wrapper div.  Then importing the nested ajax call into that.  I do believe this was similar to the solution you gave in the possible duplicate question.  So is the load function mostly used to replace content only when there is an empty wrapper div to call from?  Is there a better way to just replace content to content like I'm trying to do?  ...creating the wrapper, to me, seems like a patch sort of fix especially if you have multiple instances on one page you'd have a ton of unneccesary divs

Comment: `.load` is usually used when the server returns just the contents. For instance, if you're filling in a table, the server would return all the `<tr>` tags, and you would load it into the `<table>` element.

Comment: The other way you could solve this is by using `.get()` instead of `.load()`, and have your callback function use `.replaceWith()` on the `#content` DIV.

Comment: Thanks that clears it up a bit for me.  And even though it's working now with the wrapper I may try get() and replaceWith() instead

Answer (score 2):

I know am late but i hope this helps someone else just like it did for me when i arrived this page.
You can escape the nested `<table>` or `<div>`;

INSTEAD OF:

```
$("#table_id").load("page.html #table_id");
```

USE THIS RATHER:

```
$("#table_id").load("page.html ##table_id > *");
```

This will cause your `<table>` from not duplicating and guess what, your table css will remain the same!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This actually worked for me. If it is not too much trouble can you explain what is going on within this code? It took several days of research before I found this answer. I gave you an upvote. Thanks