# .load() is creating a completely new div container

Tags: jquery, razor

I have a partial view that is refreshed with new data periodically. When I try to load the new data with `.load()` it adds a duplicate div container tag. I've also tried `.get()` and `.replacewith()` with the same [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328867/having-trouble-loading-table-after-ajax-post) but I can't get the same results

**Partial**

```
<div id="marqueeTop">
    <span class="moveTop">
        @foreach(var item in Model){
            <label class="totalSales">
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.GroupName)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Sales ).....
            </label>   
        }
    </span>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#marqueeTop').load('/Home/GetBookingsTicker', function () {
});
```

**Image of the duplicate tag**

[image]

Comment: of course it does.. you have a div with id marqueetop in your partial. load() will load all the response inside the selector before.. just remove the div container with the id marqueeTop out of your partial or call load() on a parent..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add a container outside the partial view:

```
<div id="MarqueeContainer">
    @Html.Partial("_MarqueePartial");
</div>
```

---

```
$('#MarqueeContainer').load('/Home/GetBookingsTicker');
```

---

Or use a different ajax function:

```
$.get('/Home/GetBookingsTicker', function(response) {
    $('#marqueeTop').replaceWith(response);
});
```